# R update values within a grouped df with information from updated previous value

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, purrr, lag

I would like conditionally mutate variables (`var1, var2`) within groups (`id`) at different timepoints (`timepoint`) using previously updated/muated values according to this function:

```
change_function <- function(value,pastvalue,timepoint){
  if(timepoint==1){valuenew=value} else
    if(value==0){valuenew=pastvalue-1}
    if(value==1){valuenew=pastvalue}
    if(value==2){valuenew=pastvalue+1}
  return(valuenew)
  }
```

`pastvalue` is the **MUTATED/UPDATED** value at `timepoint` -1 for `timepoint 2:4`

Here is an example and output file:

````
``` r
#example data
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),timepoint=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),var1=c(1,0,1,2,2,2,1,0),var2=c(2,0,1,2,3,2,1,0))
df
#>   id timepoint var1 var2
#> 1  1         1    1    2
#> 2  1         2    0    0
#> 3  1         3    1    1
#> 4  1         4    2    2
#> 5  2         1    2    3
#> 6  2         2    2    2
#> 7  2         3    1    1
#> 8  2         4    0    0

#desired output
output <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),timepoint=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),var1=c(1,0,0,1,2,3,3,2),var2=c(2,1,1,2,3,4,4,3))
output
#>   id timepoint var1 var2
#> 1  1         1    1    2
#> 2  1         2    0    1
#> 3  1         3    0    1
#> 4  1         4    1    2
#> 5  2         1    2    3
#> 6  2         2    3    4
#> 7  2         3    3    4
#> 8  2         4    2    3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
````

My Approach: use my function using `dplyr::mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars=vars(var1,var2),
            .funs=funs(.=change_function(.,dplyr::lag(.),timepoint)))
```

However, this does not work because if/else is not vectorized

**Update 1:**

Using a nested ifelse function does not give the desired output, because it does not use updated `pastvalue`'s:

```
change_function <- function(value,pastvalue,timepoint){
  ifelse((timepoint==1),value,
         ifelse((value==0),pastvalue-1,
                ifelse((value==1),pastvalue,
                       ifelse((value==2),pastvalue+1,NA))))
  }

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars=vars(var1,var2),
            .funs=funs(.=change_function(.,dplyr::lag(.),timepoint)))

     id TimePoint  var1  var2 var1_. var2_.
  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1         1     1     2      1      2
2     1         2     0     0      0      1
3     1         3     1     1      0      0
4     1         4     2     2      2      2
5     2         1     2     3      2      3
6     2         2     2     2      3      4
7     2         3     1     1      2      2
8     2         4     0     0      0      0
```

**Update 2:**

According to the comments, `purrr:accumulate` could be used

Comment: The `if/else` is not vectorized

Comment: thank you @akrun. Can I just leave if/else out and use only if instead?

Comment: You can use the vectorized `ifelse` but I wonder whether your expected output is correct

Comment: The expected output is correct. I am stuck with a nested ifelse

Comment: What I try to get is kind of an iterative process, `pastvalue` is the updated value of the previous timepoint

Comment: If that is the case you need `accumulate`

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question accordingly and try to read up on `purrr::accululate`

Comment: Thank you for the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to akrun I could get the correct function:

```
# write a vectorized function
change_function <- function(prev, new) {
  change=if_else(new==0,-1,
          if_else(new==1,0,1))
  if_else(is.na(new), new, prev + change)
}

# use purrr:accumulate 
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars=vars(var1,var2),
            .funs=funs(accumulate(.,change_function)))

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id timepoint  var1  var2
  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1         1     1     2
2     1         2     0     1
3     1         3     0     1
4     1         4     1     2
5     2         1     2     3
6     2         2     3     4
7     2         3     3     4
8     2         4     2     3
```